# Bitmap index support in different databases

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, db2, sybase

Could someone tell which database implementations currently support bitmap indexes? The only answer I know for sure is Oracle and probably DB2. Please provide supporting references.

Comment: If someone wantes to close the question, please write comment with explanation first.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is practical, or answerable.  Are you asking about all databases (which would create a never-ending list), or just those tagged?  And why exactly do you want to know this?  I don't see how this question would help other people; for example, I can't see a situation where I'd buy a database just because it supports bitmap indexes.  But these issues could probably be resolved by updating the question.

Comment: I don't know if my question will help someone, but it will definitely help me. This is Q&A site. I'm interested in most popular DBs, I tagged just a couple cause I was not allowed to tag more.

Comment: Wikipedia has this information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Indexes

Comment: Thanks I seached for bitmap indexes, that's why I didn't find this list. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a list in the [indexes section of this Wikipedia article comparing databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Indexes).

Answer (score 2):

That's a big question, and to some extent the answer depends on what you mean by "supporting" bitmap indexes.

Although I know very little about it, I believe Oracle allows you to explicitly create a bitmap index for later use.

Some other databases, including PostgreSQL and DB2, for example can use bitmaps during query processing. These are sometimes called "dynamic" bitmap indices. Whether these qualify as "real" bitmapped indices depends on whom you ask.

You can find additional reading by googling "[database name] bitmap index". Here are some articles I found useful...

- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bitmap_Indexes
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sharma-indexes-093638.html
- http://www.zinox.com/node/16
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Oracle_and_DB2,_Comparison_and_Compatibility/Storage_Model/Indexes/DB2

Answer (score -1):

Sybase IQ supports bitmap indexes.  Sybase ASE does not.